# BackBarButtonItem changes when adding rightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to add a backButtonItem but it's being removed when I later add a rightBarbuttonItem.

In parent view controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

This works fine until I add this in child view controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem *buttonC = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Word" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:buttonC];
```

This seems to remove the backButtonItem and replace it with a new default back button.
If I don't add the rightBarButtonItem the backButtonItem works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: I want to just confirm it's right or left button

Comment: It's the right button.

Comment: Actually I found out what causes the problem. It's the title of the view controller which is to long. When I shortened it down it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button_1" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(button_1:)];

UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button_" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(button_2:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=@[anotherButton1,anotherButton2];
```